# How to keep temporary instance of a model object

Tags: django, django-models

Product model connects Order model via Foreignkey. Order model has an order instance for product pen. Now if pen is deleted from product how to keep a temporary instance for product as long as the order isn't completed.

check the picture attached to see the models.

[image]

Comment: you nead to use @transaction.atomic

Comment: see the doc:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow! Please add the code for model in your question instead of using an image, this will help those who can answer your question.